# Python find all fuzzy matching sequences in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a large string and I want to find all the input sequences that are matching in this string.

So for example, I want to find all the possible matches of *defensive rebound* in:

> Player xy had 10 **defensive rebounds** only in the 3rd quarter of a match that was a defensive battle between 2 teams that have a **defensive rebound rate** of over 80% and moreover the average number of **rebounds in the defence** by player was a staggering 3.5

I want to find all the bold words and after that extract them.

I managed to build a script that does the extraction but it only works for exact matches.

I was thinking of using `difflib.SequenceMatcher` but I got stuck.

Comment: I can already give you a headstart, seeing that you have included `regex`to the list of keywords: regular expressions are used to investigate texts for lines, containing a certain content (e.g. `grep -i rebound` will search for all lines, containing the word rebound (case insensitive). Once you have found those lines, you need to address other technologies than regular expressions to find the entries within those lines.

Comment: You have to define first what are synonym. for example for a computer it is all but obvious  that "defensive" and "defence" is similar. Secondly for me I see how "defensive rebounds" is related to "rebounds in the defense" but how "defensive rebound rate" is related ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

#Find [defence(s)][space][rebound(s)][space][any word]
re.findall('defensive[\w]* rebound[\w]* [\w]+', s)

#Find [rebound(s)][space][any word][space][any word][space][any word]
re.findall('rebound[\w]* [\w]+ [\w]+ [\w]+', s)
```

`findall` returns a list of matches

If all your matches are in the same form of bold words you can extract them with:

```
re.findall('rebound[ \w]*defence', s)
re.findall('defensive[\w]* rebound[\w]*[ rate]*', s)
```